# Is there a magic function for handling missing type reference?

Tags: php

There is magic method `__call` which allows to intercept call to missing method.

I am looking for something similar -- a handler (a function) put in given namespace (say MySpace). So when I write:

```
\MySpace\MissingType::printHello();
```

This handler would be triggered and I would have the ability to log such action, create type on fly, do something else.

Is there a way to handle missing type reference in PHP?

*I use PHP7.*

Comment: What's `MissingType` supposed to be? Is it meant to be a class name?

Comment: So what you want is a magic method that can handle missing classes if `MissingType` doesn't exist? Take a look at writing a custom autoloader that will create an [anonymous class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) if a requested class doesn't exist

Comment: @Mark, could you please post it as a regular answer, thank you.